Linux/ubuntu 22.04 block device busy?
For context ... I just built a new qcow image using packer based on Ubuntu 22.04.  Most of our custom ansible roles are just reused from Ubuntu 20.04 and we are finding a few discrepancies.
As part of the  customisations we install a service that will format a drive with label "ephemeral0".  The problem is, on first boot, when this service runs, apparently the device is "busy"
Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/vdb' failed with exit code 1.
14:32:46,509 - DataSourceConfigDrive.py[DEBUG]: devices=['/dev/sr0', '/dev/vdb'] dslist=['ConfigDrive', 'None']
Device /dev/vdb is in use. Cannot proceed with format operation.
WARNING: Device /dev/vdb already contains a 'vfat' superblock signature.
Device /dev/vdb is not a valid LUKS device. 

Once I access the instance, the device is still in this state, and if I try to run any mount or format commands (E.g. cryptsetup luksFormat) I just get something like:
WARNING: Device /dev/vdb already contains a 'vfat' superblock signature.
Device /dev/vdb is in use. Cannot proceed with format operation.

I've tried lsof, mount and all the other tools suggested out there but I cannot figure out what is holding access to my /dev/vdb device.
Now if I simply reboot the instance, when it comes back up, the formatting service runs fine and I have my newly formatted LV, however due to the nature of our environment, this is not a valid workaround.
How can I figure out what is really accessing this device?  Maybe in a non-default NS?

Update:  This looks like it could be something to do with cloud-init.  If I remove the contents /var/lib/cloud/instances before I do the recovery reboot, we end up in the same state.

Update2: So it looks as though the mount is just refusing to umount properly.  After disabling our local formatting service and letting cloud-init do it's thing, the ephemeral0 drive is mounted and there is an entry in /etc/fstab:
/dev/vdb    /mnt    auto    defaults,nofail,x-systemd.requires=cloud-init.service,_netdev,comment=cloudconfig   0   2

But even after umount /dev/vdb I can't run mkfs against that device.  I always get "/dev/vdb is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!"
again lsof is not giving me any clues. Seems to be something specific to what cloud-init is doing on "first boot".
If I:

Reboot the machine after first boot the custom service is able to reformat the drive.
Set mounts: [[]] in cloud-config the custom service is able to reformat the drive is able to format the ephemeral drive on first boot.


Did you run lsof as root or as an unprivileged user?

I ran as privileged user, right after umount.
